# Implement a method using a function value in Scala

Tags: scala

Is it possible to provide an implementation of a method using a function object/value? I would like to write something in the spirit of:

```
abstract class A { def f(x:Int) : Int }

class B extends A { f = identity }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And to complement [deamon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238134/deamon) and [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53013/daniel), here's another:

```
abstract class A { def f: (Int)=>Int }
class B extends A { val f = identity _ }
class C extends A { def f = identity _ }
class D extends A { def f = (x:Int) => -x }
```

If you are stuck with a normal def, then the best you can do is

```
abstract class Z { def f(x:Int):Int }
class Y extends Z { def f(x:Int) = identity(x) }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a field of type function like this:

```
abstract class A { val f: (Int) => Int}

val identity = (x: Int) => x*x

class B extends A { override val f = identity }
```

Comment: And is there a difference between a method and a value like this? (P.S. identity is already define id Predef, and I don't want it to square the argument ;)

Comment: Methods in Scala are *not* first-class entities. Values are. Functions are values (functions have to be first-class for just about any definition of a functional language). Methods are lifted to functions through partial application.

Answer (score 3):

Just to complement [deamon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238134/deamon)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124804/implement-a-method-using-a-function-value-in-scala/2124868#2124868), here's one alternate example:

```
abstract class A { val f: (Int) => Int }
class B extends A { val f: (Int) => Int = identity _ }
```